# Route::get format in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-8

I want to create a web page that can switch into different languages, I found some tutorial but seems not used anymore for laravel 8

I want to convert this to Laravel 8 format

```
Route::get('landingpage/home', 'LanguageController@index');
Route::get('landingpage/change', 'LanguageController@change')->name('changeLang');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the Controller before you are going to use it in the Route

```
use App\Http\Controllers\LanguageController;

Route::get('landingpage/home', [LanguageController::class,'index']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('landingpage/home', [LanguageController::class,'index']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of being thorough:

```
Route::get('landingpage/home', 'App\Http\Controllers\LanguageController@index');

----

Route::get('landingpage/home', ['App\Http\Controllers\LanguageController', 'index']);

----

use App\Http\Controllers\LanguageController;

Route::get('landingpage/home', [LanguageController, 'index']);
```

A supplemental answer.